# How to Escape HTML URL via XML

Tags: html, xml, escaping, html-escape-characters

So we just got a new phone system in the office. I am trying to figure out if there is a possibility to store contact photos of the various people in the company contact list outside of the individual phone storage. Currently we have to upload a photo for each person for each phone (since it is stored internally). We are able to import/upload a XML file to the phone. Below is where I am currently:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contactData version="1.0">
    <phonebook>
        <contact sDisplayName="Test" sOfficeNumber="1111" sMobilNumber="2023929323" sOtherNumber="" Account_Id="8" Ring_Id="0" sGroupName="" photoCustom='..\i.imgur.com\ul8Hmru.jpg' photoSelect="0"/> 
    </phonebook>
    <blacklist/>
    <groupinfo/>
</contactData>
```

The images uploaded show as http://192.168.x.x/head_icon/imagename.jpg, when uploading the above xml, I got out of the head_icon folder and get it to show http://192.168.x.x/i.imgur.com/ul8Hmru.jpg. Is there a way to further escape the local IP so it goes and makes an attempt to fetch the image (allowing us to do a mass import of contacts storing the photos online somewhere)?

Comment: Looks like you just need to add http:// as in `http://i.imgur.com/ul8Hmru.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

The value of the attribute photoCustom is using a relative URL, you need to specify an absolute URL (full path, starting http://)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contactData version="1.0">
    <phonebook>
        <contact sDisplayName="Test" 
                 sOfficeNumber="1111" 
                 sMobilNumber="2023929323" 
                 sOtherNumber="" 
                 Account_Id="8" 
                 Ring_Id="0" 
                 sGroupName="" 
                 photoCustom='http://192.168.x.x/i.imgur.com/ul8Hmru.jpg'
                 photoSelect="0"/> 
    </phonebook>
    <blacklist/>
    <groupinfo/>
</contactData>
```